# C# wrapper for importing .dll, "Attempted to read or write protected memory"

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vb6, pinvoke

After a mountain of research and experimentation, I still can't figure out an issue I'm having with accessing un-managed functions from an external library.

*Quick relevant backstory: I wrote an application in Visual C++ to drive an external meter that connects to the system through USB, but is virtualizing a serial port, and I was noticing weird output behavior. In order to vindicate themselves, the manufacturer wants me to use their .dll to control the meter from my application. Fine, but....*

I wasn't able to include this .dll directly as a reference (name & path removed):[image]

So In order to use it, I presumably looked to DllImport. Instead of including the code directly into my application, I decided to make my own assembly as a wrapper for the driver so I could access the functionality through a class. After doing a dumpbin /exports on the .dll, I found the entry points for all the functions and made a C# class library like so, with only the relevant examples included:

```
namespace Meter
{
    public class PortDrv
    {

        [DllImport("PortDrv.dll", EntryPoint = "SERIALNUMBER",
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
            CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern long SerialNumber(Byte Index);

        [DllImport("PortDrv.dll", EntryPoint = "OPENPORT",
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
            CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int OpenPort();

    };
}
```

The function prototypes were pulled from the .pdf they sent me describing their library:

```
SERIALNUMBER (ByVal Index As Byte) As Long
OPENPORT () As Integer
```

And is also used in their sample VB program:

```
Private Declare Function SerialNumber Lib "PortDrv" Alias "SERIALNUMBER" (Index As Byte) As Long
Private Declare Function OpenPort Lib "PortDrv" Alias "OPENPORT" () As Integer
```

Still with me? Ok. So after compiling my own assembly, I added the reference to my application and accessed the wrapper as such:

```
int port_return = PortDrv::OpenPort(); 
Byte bite = 0x31;
__int64 serial = PortDrv::SerialNumber(bite);
```

But it bombs after trying to retrieve the serial number:[image]

And I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong. Some of the functions return correct information, but it appears any that I have to pass information to fail. I've tried all different combinations of CharSets & CallingConventions, I've set the ExactSpelling to true, etc. Is there anything glaringly obvious that I'm doing wrong, or can I just not use this library in my current environment?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that, the reason I pass '1' into the function is that, if there is only one meter connected to the system, the "Index" would be 1. If there were 2 meters, I could access the second one by passing in '2'.

Comment: Ouch. I don't suppose the manufacturer can either provide you with a .NET wrapper, or working sample code for a .NET environment? Given the apparent difficulties, this doesn't seem like an unreasonable request.

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure 0x31 is valid input?

Comment: @Cameron: I believe so. I've tried passing in '1' & 1 as well. I wanted to rule out all possible incorrect interpretations by explicitly stating the character. Or are you implying I should pass in 0x01

Comment: The code that access your C# wrapper class appears to be C++/CLI code. Why did you make a C# wrapper class that access a C/C++ code. I am going to guess the calling convention for C++/CLU is NOT StdCall.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's all they offered me, and also what is offered on their website. I could ask them, but they haven't fielded my e-mail for well over a week when I confronted them with the issue initially :)

Comment: The Integer data type in VB is 16 bit in size and the Long data type is 32 bit in size. So, I think you have to change your interop signature. Use short instead of int (OpenPort) and int instead of long for SerialNumber.

Comment: @Hans no dice. Changed all ints to shorts and all longs to ints, same result.

Comment: @Brett Does the sample VB program work?

Comment: @Lukazoid Yes it does. It was written in VB6.

Comment: @Ramhound since it is called by standard vb it should be stdcall, IE WINAPI on the C side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sample VB program you gave:

```
Private Declare Function SerialNumber Lib "PortDrv" Alias "SERIALNUMBER" (Index As Byte) As Long
```

Doesn't say `ByVal`. The default in VB is `ByRef`. Is this a typo on your part or is that the problem? If so you need to say `ref Byte` in your signature to SerialNumber.

Moral: Always say `ByRef` or `ByVal`.

Comment: the above line was included in THEIR sample program of using the driver. It kind of seemed like you may have thought that was my code, but no, I pulled it verbatim so it's correct. In their prototype, the byte is passed ByVal: `SERIALNUMBER (ByVal Index As Byte) As Long`. Is that a hiccup on their part?

Comment: I changed the signature to ref Byte and the memory fault has subsided, but the function still returns nothing (using int and long). I want to mark your answer as correct since that was the focus of the topic, but as my issue still isn't gone, I want to leave it open for now.

Comment: Yeah I suppose the prototype was wrong. Thanks for the keen eye, Ben.